# Edit a recorded strava activity?

Tags: training, bike-computer, strava

I am wondering if its possible to edit the strava activity recorded by strava app for any errors ( Time, distance W.R.T to cyclo computer)

The requirement for same is due to variance in results from on-board computer and strava app. Its is possible to enter the details manually however the valuable HR data is lost this way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Simple -- write your own program!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes this is possible.   First up I'll be completely blunt

> If you're editing your ride to make it look faster, then you're only cheating yourself.

---

**EDIT - THIS WENT AWAY in 2017ish**.     However I know strava's app sometimes just stops.  If you have a **damaged** ride in strava, then use  the SNAP tool at http://strava-tools.raceshape.com/snap/  Feed in the activity ID number which is in the URL when you view the activity.  Then you can tweak portions of your ride back to fit.  SNAP will let you download a GPX file, which can then be uploaded to Strava.com with the upload file function.  Please note, you will end up with two rides, and it will say "Atul rode with Atul" which is wrong.  Once you're happy the new ride is good, delete the old ride.

---

If you've got a ride that was seriously truncated, and SNAP won't let you tweak it, then you have more to do.

**Android Users**

1. Open Google's timeline at  https://www.google.com/maps/timeline?pb   then click Today and see how your ride path was - if its no good then give up here.
2. Click the gear icon in the bottom right corner and choose "Export this day to KML"  save the file called history-2017-01-28.kml
3. We need to massage the KML fle to GPX format.  First time I did this was manually with lots of copy and paste which was horrible.  But since then someone's created    https://kml2gpx.com/
   which does a fair job.
4. So upload the gpx file to strava, and then use the crop tool to trim it down.
5. Since google only takes a location point once a minute, compared to strava's 0.1-10 points/sec the track is a lot chunkier.   Use the SNAP tool as mentioned earlier to get it back on track.

**Apple Users**
I have no idea - does apple have any tracking like google?

**Newton / iBike / powerpod**
Grab the Isaac software from http://www.ibikesports.com/support/isaac-software-downloads/  and see if it can help.

**Garmin / other bike computer**
If your dedicated hardware has munched the ride, you may be stuffed too.  Check out forums - there could be a way to get some info back.

**Last Resort**
You can create a track in Google Maps and "save as" a KML which can then be massaged into a GPX file.  This is long and tedious, and your times will be completely made up.

**Last-Last Resort**

A GPX file is only an XML formatted text file.  You can generate one by hand with a text editor.  The format can be seen by downloading an existing ride.

Good to "make up" your distance.  You set a point at every turn and give it a time.  Elevation can be omitted.  I have used my gopro footage as a timebase to figure out offsets between turns/points.  This will produce straight lines between corners with a steady speed between them.  Also, you won't match many segments because of a lack of points

**Ultimate Final Last Resort** So your best plan is to

> Obey rule 5, and go do the route over again.

Comment: Anyone with apple or garmin info, please either add your own answer or edit this one.

Comment: Thank you! I had two instances where the app just froze and shows me wrong info. I am guessing its my phone, will try your steps if I see this again

Comment: @Atul try to minimise other apps, especially those that use the GPS.   When I had a cheap single core samsung phone, the app would be starved for CPU sometimes,  so don't even use it when doing a strava run.  Unlocking it to check the screen is okay, but taking photos would kill the recording.   A better-specc'd S5 active works much more reliably.

Comment: Just interested: why do these things happen? https://www.strava.com/activities/842314565 the beginning of the ride is somehow broken. What can be done to avoid it?

Comment: @k102 that looks like you started riding while the unit still had a poor GPS lock.  Assuming the start green dot in Lesnoi is your start, then the Garmin kept its last known location at shutdown.  But the GPS coverage was poor for the first 82 seconds and GPS lock was hard to establish.   The only fix I've found is to start the recording a few minutes before you leave.  I start Strava, then get my shoes and gloves on, start the gopro and then leave.    Consider asking a fresh question, or using the [chat] room.    Also join the SE strava club at  https://www.strava.com/clubs/181338

Comment: @Criggie thanks! Although, se strava club is too tough for me)

Comment: I have never had issues with my Garmin stuff and never used Strava. I know you can download a GPX of your Garmin data and possibly use that to upload into Strava I assume as that is a pretty common file format.

Answer (score 2):

On a Desktop, I would highly suggest gpx.studio https://gpxstudio.github.io/ if you ever need to edit your Strava maps. On my first 3mi run, I had a problem with my GPS and was easily able to correct and input an honest time/pace ( before I edited it, it said I had a 3min mi pace... not even close to what I really did. I then changed it up to a little under 8min pace). Highly recommend it, another bonus, its open source!

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's astonishingly cool.  Do you have any affiliation with the linked site?

Comment: Sadly, I am not affiliated... kinda wish I was though! The developer is obviously very talented and I am just trying to spread a program/service I found to be extremely helpful. I do a lot of cycling and also got into running due to the pandemic. Just picked up Strava and found gpxstudio after my phone messed up the GPS data (just got a bunch of straight lines that didn't follow the trail).